# Here-API can not find normal.day.yaml

Tags: here-api

I have been experimenting with here maps. When I started the project I was minimising the project code and everything was working as expected.

However, in order to debug the project I stopped minimising the code. Now when loading here maps I get a 404 trying to load:

http://localhost:8082/vendor/here-maps//styles/omv/miami/normal.day.yaml

I have looked back at my code that was working, (when I was minimising the code) and the url was:

https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1.17.2/styles/omv/miami/normal.day.yaml

Why has the url changed when I stopped minimising the code?

How do I correct the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi ee0jmt, no idea why the previous comment was deleted by others. 
Could you provide us more details like a sample code shows what you've done or how did you use it? Then we can have a look.

Meanwhile, you might be interested in this example. https://developer.here.com/tutorials/javascript-api/

Comment: moreover, you can also try this https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/#16.285/52.537696/13.387613

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did find a solution, but not quite sure why. I had stored the here-maps libraries locally rather than referencing them from the cdn. When I referenced them from the cdn it would work un-minimised.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is here bugs? I only get 3 working, and others when request tile.png get error 404

```
             var here_apiKey = '....'
            var appId = 'xxx';
            var appCode = '......';
            var urlTpl =
            'https://{1-4}.{base}.maps.cit.api.here.com' +
            '/{type}/2.1/maptile/newest/{scheme}/{z}/{x}/{y}/256/png' +
            '?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}' +
            '&apiKey={api_key}';
```

I can get these working :

```
            satellite.day

             hybrid.day

              terrain.day
```

But when request tile.png get error 404 on these:

```
                pedestrian.day

                normal.day.transit

                normal.day
```